# webkit browsers intermittently show image in slideshow off to the right of the slideshow

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, padding

I didn't notice this when I launched the site, but built my new mac and its happening in both chrome and safari.

http://coatesconstruction.co.uk/

The image in the slideshow is off to the right, as if it's not following the positioning it's supposed to.  Before I spend ages digging in the CSS, is this something you gurus have seen before and know the quick fix for? Or, do I need to swap to a different slideshow script?

Comment: I can't reproduce in Safari or Chrome (Windows 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img style="border-left-width: 450px; 
border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-right-width: 450px;      
border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 1; " 
src="/media/photographs/fp001.jpg">
```

There's a 450px border-left on the image, that's probably the cause

Also your `div #fullsize` has no `overflow:hidden;` specified, which leads to a side scrolling page in Chrome 12 on XP

Comment: found the js that was setting that, commented it out and its fixed the issue. need to test in other browsers, thanks for the comment